# "No network connection" in Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: networking, wireless, lubuntu, network-manager

About 3 days ago my wife did an update using *software updater* on her Packard Bell dot-s notebook running **Lubuntu 14.04**. Since then the wifi doesn't work. The applet icon has a little x and the menu show everything greyed out, although enable networking is ticked, enable wifi is not. `lspci -nn | grep Network` shows up the correct network controller **(Intel Corporation Centrino Wirless-N 1000)**, `ifconfig` shows only **eth0** and **lo**. The `/etc/network/interfaces` file looks like:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

When I add the following to the file:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

All it does is make the system wait at boot time with **Waiting for network configuration...** after which it explains it will wait another 60 seconds then boots without wifi connection.

After booting `ifconfig` shows **lo** and **wlan0** although there is no `inet addr:` in **wlan0**. Upon entering `sudo ifup wlan0` it comes up with `ifup: interface wlan0 already configured`. I don't know how to get this to work again. I have tried various sites with no luck.

Output for `ps aux | grep -i network` is:

```
mywife    2543  0.0  0.0   4684   840 pts/9    S+   19:44   0:00 grep --color=auto -i network
```

and output for `dmesg | grep iwl` is:

```
[   16.446434] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: irq 43 for MSI/MSI-X
[   16.539321] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 39.31.5.1 build 35138 op_mode iwldvm
[   16.856846] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[   16.856857] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[   16.856865] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
[   16.856874] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 1000 BGN, REV=0x6C
[   16.864095] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
[   16.871420] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to disable radio.
[   17.104178] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
[   17.778569] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: RF_KILL bit toggled to enable radio.
[   21.016195] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
[   21.024372] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Radio type=0x0-0x0-0x3
[   21.061736] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: L1 Disabled - LTR Disabled
[   21.069193] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Radio type=0x0-0x0-0x3
```

The output of `rfkill list` is:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

The output for the `NetworkManager --no-daemon` command is [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/17446759/)

The output for the `sudo iwlist wlan0 scanning` is [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/17447287/)

Comment: What is the result of: `dmesg | grep iwl`?

Comment: @Sneetsher the only process is `network` but doesn't include `NetworkManager`.

Comment: @chili555 I included the output above.

Comment: @Sneetsher the menu is not greyed out after running `NetworkManager --no-daemon`.  However after clicking on wireless I still can't get on the network. `ping 8.8.8.8` show `connect: Network is unreachable` and applet icon still shows `No network connection`. `ifconfig` only shows **lo**.

Comment: @Sneetsher added output for `rfkill list` above as well as two pastebins.

Comment: @Sneetsher which state do I change? `NetworkingEnabled=true WirelessEnabled=true WWANEnabled=true WimaxEnabled=true` is what it is at, at the moment.

Comment: @Sneetsher not sure what you mean by **hard enabled** or **hard disabled** and how to achieve this. I rebooted after killing NetworkManager and now menu is greyed out again and this time it shows **Networking disabled** over the icon instead of **No network connection**. I did change the `/etc/network/interfaces` file to only have the loopback connection. All others removed as I assume NetworkManager is supposed to manage this.

Comment: @Sneetsher I managed to get it working before trying the **hard enabled/disabled** switch. When editing the `/var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state` I set both `NetworkingEnabled=false` and `WirelessEnabled=false` and rebooted. It came up with **Networking disabled**. I changed them both to `=true` and rebooted. Now it works.

Comment: @Sneetsher I transfered the 2 pastebins to the question and deleted them from the comments. Not sure what else I should remove as the rest did not make a difference to the solution. Only changing the values in the `/var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state` and rebooting and setting them back has helped.

Comment: @JacquesMALAPRADE, that's enough. just remove the comments, no need for others to read this pile. btw, don't forget to flag your answer as accepted solution too it will help others find solution on search page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With @Sneetsher help I managed to get this working. By setting `/var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state` file from:

```
NetworkingEnabled=true 
WirelessEnabled=true 
WWANEnabled=true 
WimaxEnabled=true
```

to

```
NetworkingEnabled=false
WirelessEnabled=false
WWANEnabled=true 
WimaxEnabled=true
```

then rebooting and then setting it back to the initial setting and rebooting it seems to work again.